# How do I interpret this header in this curl request?

Tags: ruby, http, curl

I'm looking at a curl request that has the following as its header. What does this mean?

```
curl -H 'Authorization:token token="[SOME_VALUE]"' 'https://myurl.com'
```

Furthermore I'm trying to use `RestClient` to request this URL from ruby. https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

Normally in headers it's just a `key:value`, but here this seems different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the API you want to use is adopting the [HTTP Token authentication RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-http-token-auth-01#section-1.2).

This document was a draft and it never turned into an official standard, but there are some APIs that are using it.

```
 GET /resource/1 HTTP/1.1
 Host: example.com
 Authorization: Token token="h480djs93hd8",
                      coverage="base",
                      timestamp="137131200",
                      nonce="dj83hs9s",
                      auth="djosJKDKJSD8743243/jdk33klY="
```

You can [pass custom headers](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#headers) to RestClient using the `header` option.

```
api_token = "xyz"
RestClient.get "http://example.com/resource", { :Authorization => %Q{token token="#{api_token}"} }
```

I used `%Q` to allow interpolation. If it's unclear to you, you can also use something like

```
api_token = "xyz"
RestClient.get "http://example.com/resource", { :Authorization => 'token token="%s"' % api_token }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be same as key value pair. Here the key is `Authorization` and the value is `token token="[SOME_VALUE]"`. That should be something like below as ruby hash copied from [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#headers).

```
{:Authorization => 'token token="[SOME_VALUE]"'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some additional information in headers, not just `key:value`. For example:
`Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html, text/x-dvi; q=0.8, text/x-c`

`Authorization:token token="[SOME_VALUE]"` can be used with API with token based authentication.

Token based authentication is when an API client uses a token identifier to make authenticated HTTP requests.

You can read more about this type of authentication here: http://blog.codeschool.io/2014/02/03/token-based-authentication-rails/

Comment: This doesn't answer the user request on how to send such token via the Ruby gem he mentioned.